# Given a simplex $S$ with vertex set V, show that any the convex hull of any subset $V' \subseteq V$ is also a face of $S$.

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, polytopes

Not looking for an outright solution but some back-and-forth.

My thoughts so far:

A face of any polytope $S$ can be defined as $F = H \cap S,$ where $H$ is some supporting hyperplane of $S$.

We know that every vertex in a $d-$dimensional simplex $S$ lies on $d$ unique edges. Given some subset $V'$, we'd like to show that conv$(V')$ is a face of $S.$ My idea for the proof is

1.) Show that aff$(V') \cap S^\circ = \{\}.$ The standard $d-$simplex with $d+1$ vertices is defined as $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{d+1} : \mathbb{1}x = 1, x_i \geq 0\}.$ So, its interior would be $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{d+1} : \mathbb{1}x = 1, x_i > 0\}.$ We know that aff$(V')$ is all affine combinations of the points in $V'.$ And aff$(V')$ is just the dim(aff($V'$)) $= q$ hyperplane spanned by $V'$, and all of these points have some $x_i = 0$. So, aff$(V') \cap S^\circ = \{\}$.

2.) Show there exists some supporting hyperplane $H$ such that conv$(V') = H \cap S.$ I suspect this $H$ is just the aforementioned aff$(V')$, which would pretty much complete the proof.

Does this direction seem sound? Am I on the right track, or am I missing something or making something trivial when it really isn't?

Comment: How do you define a "face" in nD ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Not sure what you mean by this; what is nD?

Comment: nD = n dimensions. Do we agree that the name simplex is for a polytope with $n+1$ vertices in $\mathbb{R^n}$, each vertex having $n$ edges connected to it ? Do you group vertices, edges, (triangular) faces, hyperfaces under the common name "face" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, we agree on that; i.e. the d-simplex is the simplex of d+1 vertices in $\mathbb{R}^d$. And "faces" is the common name for all of those things, yes.

Comment: Are you assuming that the vertex set is just the extreme points of the simplex?

Comment: I recommend transforming to another form of standard simplex, the simplex $\Delta\subset\Bbb R^{d+1}$ which is the convex hull of the standard basis vectors $e_0,...,e_d\in\Bbb R^{d+1}$. For any subset $\{i_1,\cdots,i_r\}\subset\{0,...,d\}$ the vector $n:=e_{i_1}+\cdots+e_{i_r}$ is then a normal vectors to the supporting hyperplanen that defines the face $\mathrm{conv}\{e_{i_1},...,e_{i_r}\}$.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the vertex set $V$ has $d+1$ affinely independent points.
Hence any $V' \subset V$ is also affinely independent.
Let $C = \operatorname{co} V$.

Since $V$ is affinely independent, the barycentric coordinates of any point in $\operatorname{aff} C$ are unique. Let $\mu(x)$ denote the barycentric coordinates of $x \in \operatorname{aff} C$. That is, $x = \sum_{v \in V} \mu_v(x) v$, where $\sum_{v \in V} \mu_v(x) = 1$, and $\mu_v(x)$ is the '$v$ coordinate' of $x$ with respect to $V$.

A face $F$ of a convex set $C$ is a convex subset $F \subset C$ such that every closed line segment in $C$ whose relative interior intersects $F$ has both end points in $F$.

Suppose $V' \subset V$. It is clear that if $|V'| \le 1$, or $V=V'$ then $V'$ is a face. So, suppose $V'$ is not one of these cases.

Let $F=\operatorname{co} V'$. Suppose we have a line segment $[x,y] \subset C$ such that $(x,y) \cap F$ is non empty and let
$z \in (x,y) \cap F$. Then $\mu_v(z) >0$ **iff** $v \in V'$. Let $\lambda \in (0,1)$ be such that $z = \lambda x + (1-\lambda) y$. By uniqueness, we have
$\mu_v(z) = \lambda \mu_v(x) + (1-\lambda) \mu_v(y)$ for all $v \in V$, and if $w \in V \setminus V'$, we must have $\mu_w(x) = \mu_w(y) = 0$ (otherwise
$\mu_w(z)>0$). In particular, $\mu_w(x) = \mu_w(y) = 0$ for all $w \in V \setminus V'$ and so $x,y \in F$. Hence $F$ is a face.